# Sorting of 1 million integers ranging from 1 to 9 using Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Given a collection of 1 million integers between 1 to 9. How would you sort them in an efficient manner ?

```
Input: [1,2,5,4,7,8,9,6,5,4,2,3,6,5,8]  
Output: [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,9]
```

Comment: use counting sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: Use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Comment: @khelwood I doubt this exercise would allow the use of Arrays.sort. This is a common interview question. Also, Arrays.sort would be O(n log n), where as counting sort is O(n).

Comment: Basically set up an array of 9 counters, and count how many times each number appears in the input.  Then it should be easy to figure out how to generate the output.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I've given interviews, and anyone who says "use a library sorting function" gets extra credit.

Comment: If there were data associated with the values I'd just create 9 buckets and drop each item into the appropriate bucket.  If no data then the "bucket" degenerates into a counter.

Comment: Can any one provide me some sort of code instead of this sort() method ?

Comment: @khelwood The point of the question is not about what library functions you know how to use, it is to recognize that with a finite range of numbers you can do better than O(n log n). No one is saying write your own sorting function in production.

Comment: Here is a Java implementation of counting sort: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-counting-sort/

Comment: @khelwood For me, anyone whose says "use an O(n log n) library sorting function" in a situation where an O(n) algorithm that can be written in three lines will suffice gets negative credit.

Comment: Sashikanta, you have enough info to write the code. Create an array of counters for the number of 1s, 2s...9s. Run through the given elements counting out how many. Then loop over your counters, fill in the first count-1s as 1, next count-2s as 2 etc

Comment: @curiosu Thanks.It was a interview question though.

Comment: @sashikanta I'm confused, you asked for code and he provided you with some, what's the problem?

Comment: @Alter That code works fine.

Comment: @sashikanta I'm missing something still, how does it being an interview question affect things?

Comment: @Alter I didn't get you.What exactly u want to know.Can u explain clearly ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen , you are right and I am wrong.

Comment: @khelwood I do agree that it is interesting knowing the APIs of your favorite language, but much more interesting is to know what algorithm is actually being used by the library. Arrays.sort() as pointed by Hunter, for example uses a [dual pivot quicksort](http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf) which runs in O(n log(n)), much slower than a linear sort.

Comment: @BrunoR.Cardoso What I meant was, I'm happy when an interviewee says "I imagine there's a standard sorting function in the library I could use", though I realise this particular question has a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For big inputs, Java's `Collections.sort()` uses TimSort, which runs on **O(n log(n))**.
If you want it to run faster, let's say linear time, than you should use a non-comparison based sorting algorithm.

Since your range of integers is much smaller than the number of items to sort, that's the perfect usage for [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Being `k = 9` (range from 1-9) and `N = 1 million`. Your running time would be **O(k + N)**.

Answer (score 1):

create 10 arrays (or array of 10 arrays), one for each number, iterate your input array and add each number to the corresponding array. finally, combine all the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Input: [1,2,5,4,7,8,9,6,5,4,2,3,6,5,8]
Output: [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,9]

This can be solved in O(n) time with O(k) space.

Since the range given is 9, we can create an array of size 9+1 where each index will store the occurrence of a number in input array

TempArray = [ 0  1  2  1  2  3  2  1  2  1]
Index         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

All you need to do is to read tempArray and fill up the data back to input.

Value at index 1 is 1 so we will add only one element.

value at index 2 is 2 so we will add two time number two.

value at index 3 is 1 so we will add three only one time.

value at index 4 is 2 so we will add four only two time
....

in this way you can override the original array.

T(O(n))
S(O(k))

Let me know if you have any confusion.

here is the c# code for the same:

```
int[] input = new int[15] { 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8 };
  int k = 9;

  int[] temp = new int[k + 1];
  for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
  {
      temp[input[index]]++;
  }


  int i = 0; // used for input index
  for (int index = 0; index < temp.Length; index++)
  {
      while (temp[index]-- != 0)   // redusing count value after updating the index into input array
          input[i++] = index;
  }

  for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
  {
      Console.Write(" {0} ", input[index]);
  }
```